# add values in php based off first value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as shown below which some rows will have the same name. I am getting nowhere fast trying to do what i want to achieve.

With a foreach loop how i would go through each one add the values of the same name up and put it into a new array?

Thanks :)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Value
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name2
            [1] => Value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Value
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name3
            [1] => Value
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name2
            [1] => Value
        )
```

This only a snippet and will change to length when the csv it comes from changes weekly Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most efficient way yet but it's working the way you want it to happen.

```
<?php

$testArr = array(
            array('Name1', 1),
            array('Name2',2),
            array('Name1',3)
);
$newArr = array();
$tmp = array();
foreach($testArr as $i=>$row)
{
    if( in_array($row[0], $tmp) )
    {
        $key = array_search($row[0], $tmp);
        $newArr[ $key ][1] += $row[1];
    }
    else
    {
        array_push( $newArr, array($row[0], $row[1]) );
        array_push( $tmp, $row[0] );
    }
}

print_r($newArr);

?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name2
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

Tested working, Check it here, [phpFiddle](http://ideone.com/2lvBYP)

Comment: This works brilliant!
Is there anyway on the code to divide the total but the amount of times it adds? like for example if the total of Name1 is 10 but it has Name1 five times it will end up as 2

Comment: Yes. I run a new foreach for that, that will divide the sum and number of occurences. Check it [here](http://ideone.com/LrggzJ).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $newData[$item[0]][] = $item[1];
}
var_dump($newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the result with this approach.

```
$data_array = Array{};

$result_array = NULL;

foreach ($data_array as $value) {
    $result_array[$value[0]] += $value[1];
}
```